# SoundEffect does not play a WAV soundeffect on android

Tags: android, qt, audio, qml

I have recently added support for the sound effects replay in my Qt application and ported it to android platform.

For playing my sound file I used a `MediaPlayer` QML component, which was able to play my effect, but was useless for frequent sound, thus I needed a more efficient component, which would replay the sound effect with small latencies.

According to Qt's documentation, the `SoundEffect` should be the first choice, but for some reason the sound is not playing.

In my debug status output I can see that when `SoundEffect.play()` is triggered the `playing` is set to `true`, but then immediately reset to false. In the console output I can see this messages:

```
W QtAudioDeviceManager: Built in Earpiece may not work when Wired Headphones are connected
D AudioManager: setMode mode=2 from com.indurad.ioau
I AudioManager: In stopBluetoothSco(), calling application: com.indurad.ioau
I AudioManager: In setBluetoothScoOn(), on: false, calling application: com.indurad.ioau
I AudioManager: In setSpeakerphoneOn(), on: false, calling application: com.indurad.ioau
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::PlayerBase()
D om.indurad.ioa: TrackPlayerBase::TrackPlayerBase()
I libOpenSLES: android_audioPlayer_realize, channel mask 0x3
I libOpenSLES: android_audioPlayer_realize, create default channel mask 0x3, channels 2
I libOpenSLES: Emulating old channel mask behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based on channel count of 2)
D AudioTrackExtImpl: AudioTrackExtImpl init
D AudioTrack: set() streamType 3, sampleRate 24000, format 0x1, channelMask 0x3, frameCount 0, flags #104, notificationFrames -2, sessionId 1673, transferType 0, uid -1, pid -1 cbf 1
E AudioSystem: invalid attributes { Content type: AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN Usage: AUDIO_USAGE_UNKNOWN Source: AUDIO_SOURCE_DEFAULT Flags: 0x0 Tags:  } when converting to stream
D AudioTrack: createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount 0 -> 968
I AudioTrack: createTrack_l(2091) on outputId(13) : 0x70a15a1400, mCblk = 0x721b6cc000,  mLatency = 88, mAfLatency = 48, frameCount = 968, mSampleRate = 24000, mFlags = 0, mReqFrameCount = 968, mNotificationFramesAct = 480
D ListServiceUtils: mListServiceUtils::init CallingPid 32492
D ListServiceUtils: mListServiceUtils::init this 0x70be56c740
D AudioTrack: setVolume left 0.000 right 0.000 , callingPid 32492
D AudioTrack: start(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): called with 2400 frames delivered
D AudioTrack: flush(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED
D AudioTrack: start(2091): prior state:STATE_FLUSHED output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): called with 2400 frames delivered
D AudioTrack: flush(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED
D AudioTrack: start(2091): prior state:STATE_FLUSHED output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): called with 4328 frames delivered
D AudioTrack: flush(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED
D AudioTrack: start(2091): prior state:STATE_FLUSHED output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): called with 4328 frames delivered
D AudioTrack: flush(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED
D AudioTrack: start(2091): prior state:STATE_FLUSHED output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D om.indurad.ioa: PlayerBase::stop() from IPlayer
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): prior state:STATE_ACTIVE output 13 stream 3 session 1673
D AudioTrack: stop(2091): called with 4320 frames delivered
D AudioTrack: flush(2091): prior state:STATE_STOPPED
D AudioTrack: setVolume left 1.000 right 1.000 , callingPid 32492
```

The message:

> E AudioSystem: invalid attributes { Content type: AUDIO_CONTENT_TYPE_UNKNOWN Usage: AUDIO_USAGE_UNKNOWN Source: AUDIO_SOURCE_DEFAULT Flags: 0x0 Tags:  } when converting to stream

led me to some articles, which say that the audio files should be supplied within the filesystem, but not the Qt resource system.

However, I am stuck a bit with how can one deploy assets to the android APK as is, without integrating them as Qt resources system.

I am using:

- Qt 6.4.2
- CMake for building android package.

Comment: You would have more success if you were to convert your `wav` files to either `mp3` or `ogg`. The Qt codecs are limited but the latter two formats/codecs are more likely to be cross-platform.

Comment: The wierd thingis that for mp3 and ogg formats the sound doesn't play at all. The error i get is `W ioau    : QSoundEffect(qaudio): Error decoding source qrc:/SOFTFS/assets/Lukas-beep.mp3`. Probably i am missing some qt library, whic supports mp3 and ogg

Comment: The QSoundEffect documentation clearly says that it only supports *uncompressed* formats, so trying to use mp3 or ogg files won't work. I'm not used to Android and MD in general, have you checked the documentation about [assets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/android-platform-notes.html#assets-file-system), though? Also, your file seems to have an uncommon sample rate (24000), it shouldn't be a problem, but never say never: try to convert it to a more standard rate, like 44.1k or 48k.

Comment: @musicamante, thanks for the link, i was looking for something like this to be able to provide the asset files without adding them to the qt's resources. 
I played a bit with the sampling rate and tried to play the file within different devices, and indeed it helped. It seems that on Oppo smartphone playing audio files with sampling rate < 44.1kHz doesn't work properly. Setting the sampling rate to 48kHz was optimal result.

Comment: @IvanFolbort Interesting. So, my hunch was actually right: the sampling was the culprit. I'm actually a bit surprised: I'm no Android developer, but, as far as I knew, it *should* be able to resample "affine" rates (also based on [the documentation](//developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/sampling-audio)). But here's one of the drawbacks of open systems: everyone can change anything; it seems that the Android version of your Oppo ignores resampling even if it's a *compatible* rate: according to the above docs, "half downsampling" of a conventional rate (48kHz) shouldn't be an issue. Still...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[EDIT based on @musicamante comments]

When it comes to understanding file formats, you have to realize that both the format and the inner stream codec are important.

To demonstrate, I've tested a bunch of files with both `MediaPlayer` and `SoundEffect`.

| File Format | Stream | Windows MediaPlayer | Android MediaPlayer | Windows SoundEffect | Android SoundEffect |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| .wav | pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| .mp3 | mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 206 kb/s | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| .mp2 | mp2, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16 384 kb/s | Yes | Yes | No | No |
| .ogg | vorbis, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp | No | Yes | No | No |
| .ogg | flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s32 (24 bits), 128 kb/s | No | No | No | No |

There are are several observations from the above table:

- 1. `MediaPlayer` plays more formats than `SoundEffect`. This is understood, since, `SoundEffect` is limited to uncompressed formats so that it can have lower latency.
- 2. `ogg/vorbis` plays on Android but `ogg/flac` didn't. Reinforcing that having a container supported is not enough, you need to take care of the stream codec
- 3. `wav` stereo 44100 Hz played successfully in all platforms tested

The software I used to prepare the above files was `ffmpeg`, and the script I used was:

```bash
ffmpeg -y -i test.wav test.mp3
ffmpeg -y -i test.wav test.mp2
ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -acodec libvorbis -vn test_ogg_vorbis.ogg
ffmpeg -y -i test.wav -acodec flac      -vn test_ogg_flac.ogg
```

Comment: The OP is not asking about MediaPlayer, but SoundEffect. The former uses an underlying backend that *decodes* the source and eventually displays/plays the result. Besides, the capability of [Q]MediaPlayer depends from that of the backend, which may have absolutely nothing to do with the OS: for instance, Qt could have been built with a custom (or modified) backend, resulting in being able to reproduce a file on a configuration and not in another, even with the same OS. [Q]SoundEffect is a raw player, it uses the uncompressed data of a file source, which is then directly read from QAudioOutput.

Comment: So, while your point about the difference between format and codec is correct (to be precise, the precise distinction should be about the *container*, and also consider inconsistent file extensions), the given comparison is irrelevant for QSoundEffect, as only the first file would eventually work. Note the *would*: there's no absolute guarantee that any given uncompressed wave file will always work: most systems are perfectly capable of providing support for most standard *digital audio formats* (sample rate/depth, endianness, audio channels, etc.), but may still not be able to play some.

Comment: Some further notes, if I may. Since Qt 6.5, ffmpeg is the default backend for [Q]MediaPlayer on all platforms (except Yocto distros, see the [documentation about target platforms and backends](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtmultimedia-index.html#target-platform-and-backend-notes)), meaning that: 1. there will be no differences between Windows, Linux, macOS (iOS?) and Android; 2. since ffmpeg is more flexible, formats not previously working (like ogg/flac) may be playable now; 3. controversially, formats that could be previously available on some platform or systems, due to the backend (for instance, by »

Comment: » installing extra codec packs on Windows) may not work anymore due to license incompatibilities (see the "Licenses and attributions" section in the link above); 4. playback capabilities of uncompressed audio totally depends on the system, as the sound device may have limitations that the OS (through "drivers" or capabilities provided by the sound system) may not always fix: for instance, an incompatible sampling frequency, which seems to be the case of the OP (the source file was sampled with an unusual 24kHz rate); standard rates (44.1 and 48) are normally safe and usually available, but »

Comment: » that still depends on the system: if the target is an embedded device, it may have further limitations caused by audio capabilities and performance (eg: an audio device that only provides 8, 16, 22.05 and 24kHz, but with a limited CPU that cannot afford downsampling), meaning that an uncompressed audio file with higher sampling will not be played anyway. In any case, I suggest you to update your answer, specifying versions of both Qt and the OS (including the specific Android device/variation) used for your tests.